# Dart/Flutter: List of Object to other List of Object

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of a list, created with a constructor, like:

```
class DA_Field {   final int DAFIELDKEY;   final String strGROUP;   final String strText;   String Status;

  DA_Field({
    required this.DAFIELDKEY,
    required this.strGROUP,
    required this.strText,
    this.Status = '?', });}
```

now I want to copy this list of list in another List, like:

```
class DA_Field_val {
  final int DAFIELDKEY;
  String Status;

  DA_Field_val({
    required this.DAFIELDKEY,
    this.Status = '?',
  });}
```

where DAFIELDKEY should be the same in both Lists, Status should also be copied.

How should I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can map a list to another type of list. Something like this:
Creating new list from existing list of DA_Field

List<DA_Field_Val>list_DA_Filed_Val = list_DA_Field.map((DA_Field_item) => DA_Field_Val(DAFIELDKEY: DA_Field_item.DAFIELDKEY, Status: DA_Field_item.Status)).toList();

Full code:

```
class DA_Field {   
  final int DAFIELDKEY;   
  final String strGROUP;   
  final String strText;   
  String Status;

  DA_Field({
    required this.DAFIELDKEY,
    required this.strGROUP,
    required this.strText,
    this.Status = '?', });
}

class DA_Field_val {
  final int DAFIELDKEY;
  String Status;

  DA_Field_val({
    required this.DAFIELDKEY,
    this.Status = '?',
  });
}

void main() {
  List<DA_Field> list_DA_Field = [DA_Field(DAFIELDKEY:1,strGROUP:'xyz', strText: 'abc', Status: 'Pass'), 
                                DA_Field(DAFIELDKEY:7,strGROUP:'abc', strText: 'pqr', Status: 'Fail'),];
  List<DA_Field_val> list_DA_Field_val = list_DA_Field.map((DA_Field_item) => 
                                                         DA_Field_val(DAFIELDKEY: DA_Field_item.DAFIELDKEY, Status: DA_Field_item.Status)).toList();
  
  for (var newObj in list_DA_Field_val)  {
    print (newObj.DAFIELDKEY);
    print (newObj.Status);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - but this is my code:
`List<DA_Field_val> list_DA_Field_val = DA_Fields.map((DA_Field_item) => list_DA_Field_val(DAFIELDKEY=DA_Field_item.DAFIELDKEY,Status=DA_Field_item.Status)).toList();`
but i get this error:
`error: A value of type 'List<dynamic>' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'List<DA_Field_val>'`

Comment: Added full working code in the answer. Please check the edited answer.